# Inception network BatchNorm layer returns None gradient

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

Hi I am trying to fine tune inception network with a customized loss function. It is a triplet loss funcion.

## This function is from facenet.py

```
def triplet_loss(value, alpha):
    """Calculate the triplet loss according to the FaceNet paper

    Args:
      value: the embeddings for the anchor, positive, negative images.

    Returns:
      the triplet loss according to the FaceNet paper as a float tensor.
    """
    # The following function ensuer, it is evenly divided
    anchor, positive, negative = tf.split(value, num_or_size_splits=3, axis=0)

    with tf.variable_scope('triplet_loss'):
        pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, positive)), 1)
        neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor, negative)), 1)

        basic_loss = tf.add(tf.subtract(pos_dist, neg_dist), alpha)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0.0), 0)
        # TODO: added by me
        tf.add_to_collection('losses', loss)
    return loss
```

Note: the value param is the output of logits layer before the softmax.

When I calculate the gradient, I find out `BatchNorm/moving_variance` and `BatchNorm/moving_variance` have None gradient. Why it returns None gradient value?

And with visualization, I found there is no data flow from loss to BatchNorm scope, Why weights has dataflow from the loss node but Batchnorm doesn't ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These None gradients only belong to batchNorm layers, therefore I do some studies on batchNorm. After reading the blog post `http://ruishu.io/2016/12/27/batchnorm/` I found that

### batch normalization has distinct behaviors during training versus test time.

- Training

  Normalize layer activations according to mini-batch statistics.
  During the training step, update population statistics approximation via moving average of mini-batch statistics.

---

- Testing

  Normalize layer activations according to estimated population statistics. Do not update population statistics according to mini-batch statistics from test data.

After I set the phase key as training in the inference function, the problem is solved.